# How are enchanted more vulnerable to cantrips?

Tags: world-of-darkness, changeling-the-dreaming

I have read on some Changeling books that accepting a gift from a changeling is dangerous, because enchanted mortals are more vulnerable to changeling's magic. I have read the same about drinking changeling's blood (if you are a vampire).

But when reading cantrip and enchantment systems the only thing I have found is that you don't have to spend glamour to cast a cantrip to an enchanted being. Given that the changeling must spend glamour to enchant that person, it doesn't sound like a huge advantage, unless you are planning to cast several cantrips to the same target (which isn't very normal).

Is there another advantage when casting cantrips to enchanted targets?

Comment: @Discord Good point. But still, this is found on "The Enchanted": "This [enchanting a mortal] allows the Kithain to use their chimerical weapons and items on the mortal as well as more easily affect him with cantrips".

Answer (score 4):

> Given that the changeling must spend glamour to enchant that person, it doesn't sound like a huge advantage, unless you are planning to cast several cantrips to the same target (which isn't very normal)

However, I believe that's the advantage they're talking about. An enchanted person can be affected by multiple cantrips — plus, there's the case where *multiple* changelings want to enchant a single target. Being enchanted puts you in reach of all of them.

Answer (score 2):

### Being enchanted means you (likely) have lower banality

Being highly banal means for many charms, that you are either harder to affect to being outright immune if you are so banal that being around you is painful for the Changelings around. Having a high banality also makes it *dangerous* to enchant you, because not overcoming your banality means the changeling is hit by a banality trigger.

> To affect anything with her Glamour, a changeling must
> overcome Banality. **If a changeling attempts** to cast a cantrip,
> **enchant a mortal**, or take any other action that involves
> Glamour, **the target’s Banality affects the difficulty of the roll**.<sup>1</sup>

> If the target of a cantrip is a mortal or you crate an I
> effect in the presence of a mortal, you must first overcome
> that mortal’s Banality.<sup>2</sup>

> The base difficulty for casting a cantrip is either the subject's
> Banality + 4 or the caster's Banality + 4, whichever is higher.<sup>3</sup>

By someone enchanting you successfully, the Changeling very likely made you either an Enchanted Mortal or a Dreamer, which means your banality is usually set accordingly: Dreamers are usually Banality 4.

---

1 - Changeling the Dreaming, 20th Anniversary Edition, p.174.
2 - Changeling the Dreaming, 1st Edition, p.192.
2 - Changeling the Dreaming, 2nd Edition, p.205.

Comment: @fectin there you go: Banality always was part of the difficulty, and enchanted mortals and dreamers have lower banality than normal mortals (banality 6+)